# Java/JavaFX - using removeEventFilter outside the method it was created in

Tags: java, events, javafx, eventhandler

I have the following method:

```
public void add() {
    someObject.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
           ...
        }
    });
}
```

It makes my **someObject** do some magic tricks when I am no longer hovering it (MOUSE_EXITED). I want to remove this EventFilter now during the program with my **remove** method:

```
public void remove() {
    someObject.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, andWhatDoITypeHere);
}
```

My question is, how do I refer or point to the **EventHandler < ? super T >**, which is the second argument? Is it still possible to do it since I didn't give it any name or reference, I just made a **new** EventHandler outside my **remove** method originally?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to remove it from inside the `handle` method of this handler, it's pretty easy: You can simply refer to the handler via `this` (doesn't work with lambdas btw). Otherwise you should store a reference somewhere, e.g. a field. (Maybe overriding `equals` to always return true could be an alternative, but i wouldn't use that one, since it could easily break things and I'm not sure `equals` is used instead of `==` when checking which handler to remove)...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for not mentioning, my **add** and **remove** methods are not nested in each other or in the handler, they are part of the same class. Therefore **this** is calling a 'Node' which is not applicable. Do you have any resources please how I could store a reference, how to create one? What kind of field should I make?

Comment: If they are part of the same class, what prevents you from adding a field: `private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> filter = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {...};` and using `someObject.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, filter);` and `someObject.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, filter);`

Comment: Thank you, I did what you mentioned but I broke it into two separate parts: first I added a field to the top of my code like this **private EventHandler<MouseEvent> someEvent;** and below where my **add** method starts I further expanded it by **someEvent = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { lots of lots of code here };**

But then when I started the code there was an error message saying that the variable must be initialized first; at the top of my code! I prefer it simple and coordinated :( I always make the fields for the variables first and then I set the values further in the program

Comment: I mean where my simple **int i=3; String str = "asd";** fields are at the very top of my code where the class begins, I must have that huge EventHandler initialized with 100+ lines? Why am I not allowed to simply declare with just one line that I am going to have an EventHandler, then I will tell the program what to do with it later on?

Comment: EDIT:

What you mentioned worked perfectly; please ignore my other messages. I figured out that I can indeed setup and expand my **someEvent** EventHandler<MouseEvent> even later on, and now everything is working. Thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: @Hydraxia If you found the answer, feel free to answer your own question using what fabian said

Comment: @GigiBayte2 Yes but I want fabian to answer it rather so I don't steal his points, it was his solution after all not mine

Comment: @fabian Do you wish to create the answer?